# Creating a sparse index with pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, indexing, pymongo

I need to [create a sparse index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-a-sparse-index/) from the python script using `pymongo`.

It seems like both [collection.create_index](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.create_index) and [collection.ensure_index](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.ensure_index) don't support `sparse` option.

According to the [mongodb issue tracker](https://jira.mongodb.org) perl and php drivers do support `sparse` option to `ensure_index` command already; looks like there is no plans to make it available in the python driver..

Are there any alternative ways to create a sparse index using `pymongo`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have to agree that the documentation isn't great here, but this works for me:

`my_collection.ensure_index("mike", sparse = True)`

Comment: I've added documentation for this, thanks for bringing it to my attention:

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver/commit/9c3f456ad08b7d943e53f70f0b0919f6c7b1d676

Comment: @A.JesseJiryuDavis, and, also special thank you for all of your work on motor.

Comment: it's DEPRECATED now。